# Force Shared Google Map To Use Terrain

Tags: google-maps

I am using a shared map with bus stops and it is set to be in Satellite view. This makes it very difficult to read. Is there a way for me to change a shared map to use Terrain mode?

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget to change to terrain mode in the large legend on the left of shared maps.